# What is the name of this ui component?

Tags: user-interface

Do you know what is the name of this component? It allows the user to add some filters based on a list.

Sorry if it's not the right place to ask my question.

[image]

Comment: you should be able to tell by looking at the component's properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tags Input

Used to add keywords for search or categorizing.

Comment: Thanks! I'm going to use this library to use it =) https://github.com/aehlke/tag-it

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @Beth, you should be able to tell by checking the page's code.

For instance, in Stackoverflow, it's a `<span>` with a particular style (in Chrome, when you add a tag to a question, right-click on it, then "Inspect element")

[image]

Comment: Sure, I didn't find anything on my example.